# All images of UIScrollView are getting placed in the beginning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am new to iOS programming. I want to generate all the controls using coding and then apply constraints to achieve autosize feature. I had achieved almost my requirement except for one problem and that is all images of my UIScrollView are getting placed at very beginning and rest of the UIScrollView stays empty. I think I am having some sort of problem with my constraints and currently I am not able to resolve it.
This is my code

```
self.bgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];

NSDictionary *viewDictionary = @{@"bgImage":self.bgView,@"scrollView":self.scrollView};

NSDictionary *position = @{@"vSpacing":@0,@"hSpacing":@0};

//here I had specified the size of the background image corresponding to the view

NSArray *constraint_POS_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-hSpacing-[bgImage]-hSpacing-|" options:0 metrics:position views:viewDictionary];

NSArray *constraint_POS_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-vSpacing-[bgImage]-vSpacing-|" options:0 metrics:position views:viewDictionary];

[self.view addConstraints:constraint_POS_H];

[self.view addConstraints:constraint_POS_V];



    //here I am specifying the size of scroll view
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                              constraintWithItem:self.scrollView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                              toItem:self.bgView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                              multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0.0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                              constraintWithItem:self.scrollView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                              toItem:self.bgView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                              multiplier:0.5
                              constant:0.0]];


    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                              constraintWithItem:self.scrollView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                              toItem:self.bgView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                              multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0.0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                              constraintWithItem:self.scrollView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                              toItem:self.bgView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                              multiplier:1.0
                              constant:0.0]];





    //self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    NSInteger numberOfViews = photoArray.count;
    for (int i=0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
        CGFloat myOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
        NSLog(@"self.view.frame.size.width : %f",self.view.frame.size.width);
        UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];

        [myView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [self.view addSubview:myView];
        //here I am specifying the size of uiview
      [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:myView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                                  toItem:self.scrollView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0.0]];
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:myView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.scrollView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0.0]];

        //here I am specifying the position of uiview
         [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:myView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.scrollView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0.0]];
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:myView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.scrollView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0.0]];

        UIImageView *photos = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, myView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        //self.photos = [UIImageView new];
        [photos setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        photos.image = [photoArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [myView addSubview:photos];
        //here I am specifying the size of image view within scroll view
           [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:photos
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                  toItem:myView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0.0]];
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:photos
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.scrollView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0.0]];

        //here I am specifying the position of the image view
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:photos
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:self.scrollView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0.0]];
        [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                  constraintWithItem:photos
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                  toItem:myView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                  multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0.0]];






        self.scrollView.delegate = self;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:myView];
        NSLog(@"self.myView.frame.size.width : %f",myView.frame.size.width);

    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews,
                                             self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
   [self.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

Comment: Scrollviews and auto layout have a very special relationship. More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: Can you please tell me by looking at my code that due to which constraint i am having problem

Answer (score 1):

you can easily solve it by just using reset to suggested constraints in storyboard.First select viewController and then press right bottom menu and select reset to suggested constraints in All views tab

This worked for me.

[image]

Comment: i am not using storyboard.All of the UI objects and constraints are added through coding so please tell me something else...